# parse error in php not showing in localhost (xampp) but showing in nginx server

Tags: php, parsing

Can anyone give me a solution for the below lines of code:

```
 $filteredArray = array_filter($wordArray, function ($x) {
    return !preg_match("/^(.|a|an|and|the|this|at|in|or|of|is|for|to|em|com|be
       |with|href|me|rt|by|np|http|www)$/x", $x);
 });
```

This line not producing any error in my localhost using XAMPP, but the same line is showing an error in my nginx server (online).

What can I do for this. Why this is showing?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /hermes/bosweb26c/b2656/nf.theonlytutorialscom/agurchand/solutions/gootwit/test.php on line 10

Comment: What version of PHP is on your nginx server?  The anonymous function is only valid in 5.3

Comment: Syntax to do it right: [callback function in array filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635945/callback-function-in-array-filter)

Comment: thanks michael. php version is 5.2.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your server may not be running PHP 5.3 or later, which is needed to support anonymous functions.  Instead, you can create the function and pass it as a callback function string to `array_filter()`.

```
function wordFilter($x) {
  return !preg_match("/^(.|a|an|and|the|this|at|in|or|of|is|for|to|em|com|be
    |with|href|me|rt|by|np|http|www)$/x", $x);
}

$filtered_array = array_filter($wordArray, 'wordFilter');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your version of php on the nginx server is too old to use anonymous functions (closures -- at least PHP 5.3) is required.  You can use `create_function` to create a function in older versions, and that still works in newer versions as well.