# PHP+ Array filter function not working in server

Tags: php, arrays

I am using `array_filter()` function in PHP.
It is working in local fine, but when plce it in server it shows some error

> **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION**

My PHP version in server is `5.2.17`. Can any one tell what is the issue. If it is the version problem, how to write the equivalent code?

```
$finalarray = array_filter($finalarray, function($array) use ($from_date, $to_date) {
    $epoch = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $array['date']));
    return $epoch >= $from_date && $epoch <= $to_date;
});
```

Comment: Anonymous functions are available in 5.3 and later, not 5.2

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635945/callback-function-in-array-filter

Comment: Create a function to a variable http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php and pass this as second argument

Comment: @i have done this in different way.see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative ...

```
$toFilter = array();

foreach($finalarray as $key => $newarray) {
    $epoch = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $newarray['date']));
    // $epochAsAnAlternative = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $newarray['date']);
    if($epoch >= $from_date && $epoch <= $to_date) { // $from_date and $to_date should be \DateTime also
        $toFilter[$key] = null;
    }
}

$filteredFinalArray = array_diff_key($finalarray, $toFilter);
```

This code reduces functions call for filtering required array to 1 call - `array_diff_key`, the rest is business logic itself and a bit of overhead using separate array for storing keys that should be filtered out.

---

And it is advisable to use `DateTime` object instead of `strtotime`, because `strtotime` is not very reliable. Moreover `DateTime` objects can be compared the same way using `>`, `<`, so code will not change a lot.

Answer (score 0):

i have done this in different way.

```
foreach($finalarray as $newarray){
                $epoch = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $newarray['date']));
                if($epoch >= $from_date && $epoch <= $to_date)
                array_push($final,$newarray);
}
```